# libvirt: create a bridged network using openvswitch with dhcp enabled

Tags: vlan, bridge, libvirt, dnsmasq, openvswitch

I am trying to use libvirt + dsnmasq + openvswitch to create a bridged network with dhcp enabled. I created a libvirt network with the following XML:

```
<network connections='1'>
  <name>ovs-net</name>
  <uuid>fffd6fea-a753-4fca-b684-76fb24866ba3</uuid>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='ovsbr0'/>
  <vlan>
    <tag id='1298'/>
  </vlan>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'/>
</network>
```

I can create guests using this network, e.g.:

```
<domain>
...
    <interface type='network'>
        <mac address='52:54:00:a6:3b:48'/>
        <source network='ovs-net'/>
        <model type='virtio'/>
        <address type='ccw' cssid='0xfe' ssid='0x0' devno='0x0001'/>
    </interface>
</domain>
```

I can manually configure an IP address on the guest and send inbound/outbound traffic. When I edit the ovs-net xml to include an IP address and DHCP configuration it fails as follows:

```
virsh net-edit --network ovs-net 

<network connections='1'>
<name>ovs-net</name>
...
<ip address='10.20.101.121' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='10.20.101.121' end='10.20.101.130'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:7a:6d:e7' name='test.com' ip='10.20.101.120'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>

error: unsupported configuration: Unsupported <ip> element in network ovs-net with forward mode='bridge'
```

My networking knowledge is limited, so I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  schema essentially supports two classes of setup. The managed setup is based on a traditional bridge device that libvirt creates itself, and runs dnsmasq for DNS/DHCP service. The unmanaged setup is based on a traditional bridge, or openvswitch or macvtap or several other options. In the latter case, libvirt doesn't actually create anything itself - it is just a way to associate libvirt with the externally created network infra. As such libvirt won't run dnsmasq for these either, hence why it is rejecting your request to setup IP addrs / dhcp ranges.